# How to access qseecom driver from java code in user space

Tags: java, qualcomm, os-userspace

I want to write security APIs for my Qualcomm device with snapdragon 410c, for that purpose I want to use qseecom driver, can someone point me how can I access qseecom driver from my java code in userspace.